# Is there an official place to download AWS API definition files from?

Tags: aws-sdk

As you know, almost all AWS SDKs have API specification files in their repos in form of JSON files. [Botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore) for an example has them in `botocore/data/` directory. C++ SDK has JSON files in "code-generation/api-descriptions/", etc. Are these JSON files downloadable from somewhere, or can I generate them somehow from some reliable AWS resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to find out the answer I asked on the ##AWS FreeNode IRC channel and someone (nick: Pilate) pointed out to the folloing GitHub issue that more/less answers my question: https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/944

Apparently those JSON files are created and modified manually by people who have internal knowledge of the AWS services.